# Error 404 - Get request using @RestController - SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-restcontroller

Yes, there are lot of questions about it, but each case is unique.

The objective is write a simple application to make CRUD operations on a entity `Product`, using: `Controller`, `Model` and `Repository`.

Tree:

```
+- com.teste
  +- controller
  | +- ProductController.java
  +- model
  | +- Product.java
  +- repository
  | +- ProductRepository.java
  +- SpringEsApplication.java
```

**ProductController.java**

```
@RestController
//@RequestMapping(value="/product") // When try it, not works too (same error).
public class ProductController {

@Autowired
private ProductRepository productRepository;

@PostMapping("/saveProduct")
public long saveProduct(@RequestBody List<Product> products) {
    productRepository.saveAll(products);
    return productRepository.count();
}

@GetMapping("/findAllProducts")
public Iterable<Product> findAllProducts() {
    return productRepository.findAll();
}

@GetMapping("/findProductByCode")
public List<Product> findProductByCode(@PathVariable String code) {
    return productRepository.findByCode(code);
}

}
```

**Product.java**

```
@Document(indexName = "product_index")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Product {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String code;
    private double price;

}
```

**ProductRepository.java**

```
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends CrudRepository<Product,String> {

    List<Product> findByCode(String code);

}
```

**SpringEsApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.teste.repository"})
public class SpringEsApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringEsApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**Postman GET Request**

GET Request:

```
http://localhost:8080/findAllProducts
```

Response:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-09-18T14:10:38.305+0000",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/findAllProducts"
}
```

Even without data, it should return something.

**Console log starting**

```
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.8.RELEASE)

2019-09-18 11:16:34.061  INFO 4764 --- [  restartedMain] com.teste.SpringEsApplication            : Starting SpringEsApplication on CTDDELL5JVV862 with PID 4764 (started by augusto.cadini in C:\Users\augusto.cadini\Desktop\Spring ElasticSearch projects\spring-es)
2019-09-18 11:16:34.069  INFO 4764 --- [  restartedMain] com.teste.SpringEsApplication            : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-09-18 11:16:34.193  INFO 4764 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2019-09-18 11:16:34.193  INFO 4764 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2019-09-18 11:16:34.774  INFO 4764 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2019-09-18 11:16:34.829  INFO 4764 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 51ms. Found 2 repository interfaces.
2019-09-18 11:16:35.516  INFO 4764 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-09-18 11:16:35.544  INFO 4764 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-09-18 11:16:35.544  INFO 4764 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.24]
2019-09-18 11:16:35.671  INFO 4764 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-09-18 11:16:35.672  INFO 4764 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1479 ms
2019-09-18 11:16:35.949  INFO 4764 --- [  restartedMain] o.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService   : no modules loaded
2019-09-18 11:16:35.950  INFO 4764 --- [  restartedMain] o.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService   : loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.index.reindex.ReindexPlugin]
2019-09-18 11:16:35.950  INFO 4764 --- [  restartedMain] o.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService   : loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.join.ParentJoinPlugin]
2019-09-18 11:16:35.950  INFO 4764 --- [  restartedMain] o.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService   : loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.percolator.PercolatorPlugin]
2019-09-18 11:16:35.950  INFO 4764 --- [  restartedMain] o.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService   : loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.script.mustache.MustachePlugin]
2019-09-18 11:16:35.950  INFO 4764 --- [  restartedMain] o.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService   : loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
2019-09-18 11:16:36.901  INFO 4764 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.d.e.c.TransportClientFactoryBean     : Adding transport node : 192.168.99.100:9300
2019-09-18 11:16:37.260  INFO 4764 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2019-09-18 11:16:37.572  INFO 4764 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-09-18 11:16:37.956  INFO 4764 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2019-09-18 11:16:37.957  INFO 4764 --- [  restartedMain] com.teste.SpringEsApplication            : Started SpringEsApplication in 4.838 seconds (JVM running for 5.522)
```

Comment: Can you please share console log of starting app ?

Comment: @YogeshPrajapati edited with it.

Comment: `SpringEsApplication` doesn't scan the package with the controller (or the model).  Since the controller was not scanned no bean was created, so the endpoints were not registered.

Comment: @AndrewS so, how I solve it?

Comment: The easiest is to have `SpringEsApplication` in a base package such as `com.teste`.  Then controller, model, repo, etc., are in packages under the base package.  Then there's no need to specify which packages to be scanned since by default all packages under the starting package will be scanned.

Comment: Please, look the tree described on the question. It is like it.

Comment: Yes - see @YogeshPrajapati answer.

Comment: I need 5min to accept ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.teste.repository"})` from you main class.

It is not required in your case.

When you provide `@ComponentScan`, Spring engine will scan those packages only which you have provided.

`@ComponentScan` is required to provide custom scanning of packages/classes.

Answer (score 1):

The Person identifier is of type Long, so repository should be extends `CrudRepository<Product, Long>` not `CrudRepository<Product, String>`.

Next, rest constroller is outside of `"com.teste.repository"` package. You can remove `@ComponentScan` annotation and spring will find controller.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your `@ComponentScan`. By default Spring boot scans all packacges starting from the location of your `SpringApplication.java`. You have now overridden this and asking the container to scan only `repository`. Remove this line. Instead, use `@EnableMongoRepositories`